# How can I create a daily chart with HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, statistics

so right now i'm working on building a chart that I want to display daily information about user posts, comments, activations etc. but also have a monthly overview. So their are lines for months and days in between with points. I seem to be having a hard time finding an example or something similar so i'm coming here to see if anyone has ever done this before or has any ideas of how i can achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. What have you tried?
In general you would have a series containing daily data and a series containing monthly data. Without further info this is all the help I can give.

Comment: basically looking for something like this, but I want to load JSON and different series
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax

Comment: Well, what have you tried? There are demos that show how to read from JSON as well.

Comment: How your json looks like? and where the problem is, because it seems to be standard example. You need to add extra info in tooltip?

Comment: don't need tooltips just needed to reformat the x-axis labels and get a json file, got it all working and generating a table as well.